# Как дождаться ответа слушателя, прежде чем продолжнать выполнение

Tags: java, android, vkontakte-api, listener, android-loader

В общем, проблема такая: я пишу программу, для обработки информации о подписчиках группы с используя *VK API*. В методе `doInBackground` я пытаюсь получить количество требующихся запросов для обработки всех пользователей (*VK API* умеет возвращаться максимум по 1000 пользователей за раз). Для этого я создаю отдельный метод и в нем вызываю запрос, на который вешаю слушатель, а когда получаю результат — высчитываю нужное количество запросов:

```
    //В зависимости от числа подписчиков выбирается нужное количество
    //запросов к серверу для того, чтобы обработать всех подписчиков
    private void getRequestCount() {
        final VKRequest request = VKApi.groups().getMembers(VKParameters.from(
                VKApiConst.GROUP_ID, groupId, //id группы, у которой получаю подписчиков
                VKApiConst.COUNT, 0));        //Пока что мне не нужна информация о подписчиках

        //Посылаю запрос и вешаю слушатель
        request.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
                String jsonString = response.responseString;
                int countSubscribers = 0;

                try { //Получаю количество подписчиков
                    JSONObject jsonRootObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonRootObject.getJSONObject("response");
                    countSubscribers = jsonObject.getInt("count");
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error when parsing JSON: " + e.getMessage());
                }

                //Узнаю количество нужных запросов к серверу,
                //один запрос возвращает макс. 1000 подписчиков
                int requests = countSubscribers/1000;
                //Деление нацело вернет только целое число от деления, дробная часть —
                //оставшиеся подписчики, их забираю дополнительным запросом
                if (count % 1000 > 0) requests++;
                requestCount = requests;
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(VKError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error when requesting: " + error.errorMessage);
            }
        });
    }
```

А вот метод `doInBackground`:

```
@Override
public Object loadInBackground() {
    getRequestCount();

    ...
    ...
    ...

    return writedSubscriber;
}
```

Проблема в том, что слушатель получает ответ уже после того, как метод завершается, то есть код в `doInBackground` продолжает выполнятся, не получив ответа. Как можно "тормознуть" метод, до получения ответа от слушателя, а уже потом продолжить выполнение?

Answer (score 2):

Вам надо продолжать логику внутри метода `onComplete`, а не снаружи, в `loadInBackground`. Так вы выполните нужный код только после получения необходимых данных.

Т.е. перенесите весь код после вызова `getRequestCount` в `onComplete`

Comment: Боюсь, что этот вариант плохо подойдет. Потом будет еще куча кода и еще куча похожих запросов. Тут стоит попробовать получить ссылку на `SyncTask` и его тормозить через методы (пока спал, придумал :))..

Comment: Намеренно тормозить потоки плохая идея. Если вам не нравится как код вышлядит то просто разбейте его на методы отдельные

Comment: Да тут немножко не в этом дело... После получения требующихся запросов, в случае, если выскакивает ошибка — просто завершаю загрузку методом `return "Error on request"`, если нет — начинаю таким же методом запроса нужное количество раз получать ответы, обрабатывать и записывать в файл подходящие данные (к сожалению, алгоритм будет запутанный, однако в данном случае главное, чтобы работало). То есть тут Ваш вариант плохо подойдет, а вот ставить потоки на паузу и тд. — вполне приемлемый вариант.

Comment: Блин, `AsyncTask` не может быть поставлен на паузу...

Comment: Тогда буду морозить через `sleep` :).

Comment: Нетнетнеьне надо так. Доберусь до компа почню

Comment: Ну ладно :). А я все-таки пока что попробую, если что — откачусь.

Comment: Оно заработало! :D

Comment: @bukashka101, со `sleep`? Заработать то оно должно, но это неверный подход. Код должен выполняться последовательно. Т.е. сначала вы 1) получаете кол-во задач на загрузку, 2) в случае успеха (onCompete) начинаете их исполнять 3) по завершении исполнения одной задачи (тоже onComplete или onPostExecute) запускайте следующую. 4) Если в onError попадёте или в onPostExecute null придёт - значит что-то не так пошло и дальше просто ничего не делать.

Comment: При помощи `wait`. Я как раз делаю все, как Вы написали, просто в методе `doInBackground`, разбивая все на логичные и не запутанные блоки кода. Кстати, если я два раза подряд создаю новый `Loader` с одним идентификатором, то мне просто возвращается ссылка на мой старый?

Comment: @bukashka101, костыль вы какой-то пилите) На счёт лоадера не знаю, но должен, по идее, тот же отдавать.

Comment: Значит не зря я добавил метод `freeResources`! Возможно, но этот костыль смотрится красиво и работает :)).

Comment: Ну... Мой внутренний перфекционист испытывает боль, но, раз работает, то пусть)